# BIM 360 Model Coordination - Assigned Clashes by Modelset giving me two issues with the same clash id

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

While doing an API request to get assigned clashes by modelset, I am finding that two separate issues (#459 and #460) both were generated from the same clash. It also looks like the two issues were created within a second of each other. Does anyone from Autodesk know why this is? It is making it hard to create a dictionary with duplicate clash values in issues.

```
 {
  createdBy: YHYCJ53KWH4P,
  createdOn: 2022-07-05T14:08:39.374254+00:00,
  issueId: dbe1a6e6-82cb-41f4-b1c7-5939ba4b216f,
  id: f3b1f8b0-fc6b-11ec-aa0a-595a9ca5d82f,
  clashTestId: 13082b10-cb3b-4819-b50c-3c1aa4672747,
  [
    1402894
  ]
},
{
  createdBy: YHYCJ53KWH4P,
  createdOn: 2022-07-05T14:08:39.851239+00:00,
  issueId: 2e32b4dd-078a-4b6a-bf49-977ad518f15f,
  id: f342bc20-fc6b-11ec-aa0a-595a9ca5d82f,
  clashTestId: 13082b10-cb3b-4819-b50c-3c1aa4672747,
  [
    1402894
  ]
```

Comment: I do not hear such behavior before. Please bear with me checking with engineer team

Comment: Hi Xiaodong, any updates on this?

Comment: sorry, my inquiry had not got any respond from engineer team. It looks it was missed...I may have to finally log an internal ticket if no respond again. Could you also send me the model coordination container id of your project? your patience is appreciated

Comment: Yes, I will email it over